# Google app script : check email duplication on email column, if found same email will call another email body (google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

It is possible to send another email body if found same email address in email column. eg. column b have 2 abc@gmail.com email is same, when user input the email with same abc@gmail.com again, the user will receive email message and show that your email had been registered before.

anyone help is much appreciated.

[image: google sheets]

my code

```
    function sendmail() {
  
  Object.prototype.get1stEmptyRowFromTop = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
  const range = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, 2);
  const values = range.getDisplayValues();
  if (values[0][0] && values[1][0]) {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
  } else if (values[0][0] && !values[1][0]) {
    return offsetRow + 1;
  }
  return offsetRow;
};

  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
  
  // var lastRow = sh1.getLastRow();
  var lastRow = sh1.get1stEmptyRowFromTop(1) - 1;
  
  var email = sh1.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
  var name = sh1.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
  var registercode = sh1.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
  
  subjecttxt = "Thank you for registered with us";
  
  var email_Body;
  if (lastRow < sh1.get1stEmptyRowFromTop(3)) {
    email_Body = "Dear " + name + "," + "<br>" + "your registeration is successfully, your registered code is " + registercode + "Thank you for your registeration";  
  } else {
    email_Body = "Registration had been closed, Thank you.";
  }
  
  
              MailApp.sendEmail({
                to:email,
                subject: subjecttxt,
                htmlBody: email_Body,
              }) ;           
  sh1.getRange(lastRow, 4).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible - compare the new email value to the preexisting ones

For this, modify

```js
  var email_Body;
  if (lastRow < sh1.get1stEmptyRowFromTop(3)) {
    email_Body = "Dear " + name + "," + "<br>" + "your registeration is successfully, your registered code is " + registercode + "Thank you for your registeration";  
  } else {
    email_Body = "Registration had been closed, Thank you.";
  }
```

to

```js
  var email_Body;
  var listedRecipients = sh1.getRange("B2:B" + (lastRow - 1)).getValues().flat();
  if (listedRecipients.indexOf(email) == -1) {

    if (lastRow < sh1.get1stEmptyRowFromTop(3)) {
      email_Body = "Dear " + name + "," + "<br>" + "your registeration is successfully, your registered code is " + registercode + "Thank you for your registeration";
    } else {
      email_Body = "Registration had been closed, Thank you.";
    }
  }
  else {
    email_Body = "Your email had been registered before."
  }
```

**Explanation:**

- Getting the values of the range `"B2:B" + (lastRow - 1)` will return your all email recipients apart from the last one.
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) will convert the 2D value range into a 1D array.
- On this 1D-aray you can use the method [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to verify either the new recipient is contained in the list of the already existing ones.
- Based on the outcome you can implement an `if...else` condition.

Comment: Ziganotschka, your code is work !, thanks you so much.